# qmake: Could not find qmake configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I'm trying to install an application using the command:

```
$ qmake inst.pro
```

This fails with:

```
Could not find qmake configuration file linux-g++.
Error processing project file: /home/gabriel/test/inst.pro
```

If I check the `qmake` version I get:

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /home/gabriel/anaconda3/bin/lib
```

So it is installed, but somehow linked to my `anaconda` installation. How can I make `qmake` find the required configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple versions of Qt installed (as seems to be the case) you must make sure to use the `qmake` binary that comes with the one you want to build against. For the Qt version provided by Ubuntu you also need the `qt5-qmake` package installed, its binaries are then located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` for a 64 bit Intel machine, and this dir isn't in `PATH`. E. g. on my machine I get

```
$ which -a qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The error you get is `qmake` complaining about missing *mkspecs*, which perhaps aren't available in your *Anaconda* installation, but are part of `qt5-qmake`. You can [check the `qmake` configuration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#qmakespec) with

```
$ /path/to/your/qmake -query
```

If using the correct `qmake` binary doesn't help to solve your problem, you may perhaps be able to [override the *mkspecs* dir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html), but usually this shouldn't be necessary, and aftereffects may occur in this case.